# C++ regex_search with match on a C style array

Tags: c++, regex, c++17

I've got a C styled array (not necessarily null terminated). I'd like to search in it with regex. My code is the following:

```
const void* Search(const char* startAddress, const char* endAddress, std::regex *re)
{
    std::smatch match;
    auto ret = std::regex_search(startAddress, endAddress, *re);
```

In its current form it's working perfectly, however I'd like to know where it found that particular pattern. As soon as I add the match as a parameter, the compiler is unable to find a suiting overloaded function.
I tried making a `string_view` out of the region, but the compiler couldn't find any suitable overloaded for those iterators as well.

I'm specifically looking for `std::regex` solution. How should I use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `std::cmatch` (for `const char*`) instead of `std::smatch` (for `std::string`).

```
std::cmatch match;
auto ret = std::regex_search(startAddress, endAddress, match, *re);
```

See [std::match_results](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results)